# HuggingFace API and ReactJS For Summary

Tags: reactjs, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to make a call to the large-bert model to do a summary task but the response is always the same generic "CNN.com will feature iReporter photos in a weekly Travel Snapshots gallery. Please submit your best shots of the U.S. for next week. Visit CNN.com/Travel next Wednesday for a new gallery of snapshots. Please share your best photos of the United States with CNN iReport." Which has nothing to do with my test input from wikipedia. I tried modeling my code off of "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/docs/node/html/detailed_parameters.html#summarization-task" which is more specific to nodeJS but I figured should be very similar.

I was wondering if there was an explanation. Am I missing some input or passing the data wrong?

The following is the attempted code

```
const response = await fetch(

                "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/facebook/bart-large-cnn",

                {

                    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${API_TOKEN}` },

                    method: "POST",

                    data: {

                        "inputs": JSON.stringify(script),

                        "parameters": {"do_sample": false},

                    },

                }

            );

            const result = await response.json();

            setSummation(JSON.stringify(result[0].summary_text))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const response = await fetch(
      "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/facebook/bart-large-cnn",
      {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${API_TOKEN}` },
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify(script),
      }
    );
    const result = await response.json();
```

It appears I wasn't passing the script data properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).